# Failed to get username from request in vaadin 7

Tags: java, html, http, vaadin

I have a basic html page that sends a POST request.  In vaadin 7 I am doing the following to retrieve the POST

```
request.getParameter("username");
```

I get a null when I do this, but when I do the exact same thing in Vaadin 6 I get the actual value of the username ("john" for example).  Also if I change my method to "GET" in my html code I have not problems and get the value of the username (using the same piece of code).

Is this a bug in Vaadin 7, or do I have to implement it in a different way.

Comment: I never said "there" i asked about a very specific thing.

Comment: Oops. My bad. But it's still a horrible question title.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will solve the problem but in some cases a similar approach has worked for me. `Vaadin 7` uses `VaadinRequest` while `vaadin 6` `HttpServletRequest`. You can extract the `HttpServletRequest` from `VaadinRequest` and use it instead to get the parameter. If the request is of type `VaadinRequest`:

```
VaadinServletRequest vsRequest = (VaadinServletRequest)request;
HttpServletRequest hsRequest = vsRequest.getHttpServletRequest();
String un = hsRequest.getParameter("username");
```

Hope it hepls.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Debugging shows that Vaadin 7 internally do two requests . First request contains all parameters from URL and also from posted form. Second one , probably internal redirect , with same parameters from URL plus Vaadin UI related parameters.

So basically to capture your posted parameters, you can add [RequestHandler](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.requesthandler.html)  ,fetch it from first request and probably save it somewhere, for example at session, and then read this stored data at your component. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, It will helps you to get it.

```
VaadinRequest vaadinRequest = VaadinService.getCurrentRequest();
logger.error("User Name : "+vaadinRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName()); (OR)
logger.error("User Name : "+vaadinRequest.getRemoteUser());
```